# get html without header with boost::asio

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

i have a code to get source of html file but it get also "header response" or sth. like that (i don't know how to call it) how can i get it without this header?

my code:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

std::size_t completion(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transfered)
{
    return ! error;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::address addr = boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("31.170.161.16");
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(addr, 80);
    tcp::socket socket(io_service);
    socket.connect(endpoint);
    boost::asio::streambuf request;
    std::ostream requestStream(&request);
    requestStream << "GET /xD1azt4_panel/bhc.html HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                  << "Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n"
                  << "Host: dublersoft.hostoi.com\r\n\r\n";

    boost::asio::write(socket, request);
    boost::asio::streambuf respond;
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    boost::asio::read(socket, respond, completion, ec);
    std::cout << &respond << std::endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

and result:
[image: result]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's surprised that I also use this as my simple http client, So I just share my method, headers are put in a vector if you need it later, response data put in ostream object.

```
int do_get(std::string &host_,std::string &port_, std::string url_path,std::ostream &out_,std::vector<std::string> &headers, unsigned int timeout)
{
    try{
        using namespace boost::asio::ip;
        tcp::iostream request_stream;
        if (timeout>0){
            request_stream.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(timeout));
        }
        request_stream.connect(host_,port_);
        if(!request_stream){
            return -1;
        }
        request_stream << "GET " << url_path << " HTTP/1.0\r\n";
        request_stream << "Host: " << host_ << "\r\n";
        request_stream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
        request_stream << "Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n";
        request_stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
        request_stream.flush();
        std::string line1;
        std::getline(request_stream,line1);
        if (!request_stream)
        {
            return -2;
        }
        std::stringstream response_stream(line1);
        std::string http_version;
        response_stream >> http_version;
        unsigned int status_code;
        response_stream >> status_code;
        std::string status_message;
        std::getline(response_stream,status_message);
        if (!response_stream||http_version.substr(0,5)!="HTTP/")
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if (status_code!=200)
        {
            return (int)status_code;
        }
        std::string header;
        while (std::getline(request_stream, header) && header != "\r")
            headers.push_back(header);
        out_ << request_stream.rdbuf();
        return status_code;
    }catch(std::exception &e){
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        return -3;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is that you are going to have to use something at a higher level, if you want a separation between the headers and the body.

Another way to do it, is to just scan for \r\n\r\n which is the separator between headers/body, as is what is done in an official http request example you can find [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/sync_client.cpp) .

Answer (score 0):

A web server will always return at least a few header lines -- a few (at least `HTTP...`, and `Server:...`) are required by the RFC for HTTP.

The first blank line marks the end of the headers. After that comes the body. You'll need to read, but apparently want to ignore, all the data up to the first blank line, and retain everything after that.